# Comparing values in a csv and printing number of different pairs

Tags: java, csv

Hi and happy new year everyone!

I'm working with a `csv` file which looks like this:

```
orange | red
blue   | green
red    | red
brown  | brown
yellow | black
grey   | pink
```

My goal is scanning every row and check if each pair is made of the same item or not.

I'd like to print the total number of rows having different items.

In this case we have 4.

And I'd like also to print which row contains them, with its respective number.

In this case:

```
1 orange red
2 blue   green
5 yellow black
6 grey   pink
```

I've searched for similar questions here, but all I could find was about multiple csv files.

I'm using Java... from what I've understood so far, a good start would be:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path to my csv file"));
scanner.useDelimiter(";");
while(scanner.hasNext()){
// comparing items in rows
}
scanner.close();
```

I don't know what to do in the while loop now.

Many thanks!

Comment: Read the file line by line. For each line, split the line using the pipe separator. Check if the two elements of the line are equal or not. I don't really understand why using a scanner with `;` as the delimiter would help reading lines and splitting them using the `|` separator.

Comment: There is no pipe actually! It was just to show the two columns

Comment: Then use `;` to split each line.

Comment: What is your actual delimiter?  Given the above comments, this is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear explanation. 

My delimiter is ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation below should work, under the assumption that each line's two items are separated by semicolon with optional whitespace.  If this be not the case, then you can change the delimiter used for splitting each line.

```
int total = 0;
int rowNum = 1;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // comparing items in rows
    String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s*;\\s*");
    if (!parts[0].equals(parts[1])) {
        System.out.println(rowNum + " " + parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
        ++total;
    }
    ++rowNum;
}

System.out.println("There were " + total + " rows where the two items were not equal.");
```

Comment: It works as expected, thanks. Just one question: does scanner.useDelimiter(";"); become useless in this case?

Comment: @NoobNe0 Whitespace is part of the default delimiter, but AFAIK if you specify a custom delimiter then whitespace is no longer default.  Hence, I gave the above answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @NoobNe0 One more point: If you are sure that your CSV file _only_ has a semicolon, and nothing else, as a delimiter, then setting the delimiter this way should be no problem.

Comment: I'll try that too then!